# How to mount sftp resource using private key file in kubuntu?

Tags: mount, kubuntu, sftp

I know how to mount sftp connection in kubuntu (using Dolphin), but this way it's impossible to use private key file. Is there any way to mount a sftp resource using key file in kubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the key into *ssh-agent*. Kubuntu starts one by default, so all you should have to do is:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 2):

The SFTP kioslave supports private key authentication without SSH agent if you pass the username with the hostname, e.g.

```
sftp://test@example.com
```

in dolphin/konqueror will try authenticating with a private key and ask for its password (if the key is password protected).

P.S.  Posting here because it's pretty high in the google search results.